# Best UX/UI for displaying a list of email addresses

Tags: gui-design

I'm creating a component for a web app, and I'm looking for some advice on how to build a good UI, also considering UX.

this is an inbox page, so this page is a web email client. This app is not entirely an email client, it s a B2B app, but it has its inbox. Team emails are listed there to allow the user to know what teams he is part of quickly.

I want to show the user email, and also a list with all the team emails he has.
I'm looking for a better UI/UX as I think using an accordion doesn't look good, what other options could I use for this scenario?
A user would have one or many team emails, this is mainly why I had the idea of creating something that expands like an accordion.

The list is only for display, there is no edit or any other interaction.

[image]

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Why do you need to show team emails? Is this an address book or an email client? In which situations is this component used?

Comment: this is an inbox, so yeah this page is a web email client. This is not entirely an email client, it s a B2B app but it has its own inbox. Team emails are listed there to allow the user to quickly know what teams he is part of.

Comment: could potentially use the list to filter the "from" selected email in the future, but it's not needed now

Answer (score 1):

A contacts sidebar (perhaps with the different teams as categories) would be the expected behavior here. Putting it underneath your own email address makes them look like they're your aliases or alternative accounts or something to that idea instead.

Be aware that your coworkers also have names and faces, not just email addresses.